# Deploying Go app on Google Cloud 'missing go.sum entry'

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a simple API on Google Cloud using Go 1.19

```
> go version
go version go1.19.2 windows/amd64
```

I'm following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app#local-machine) as a template to deploy my app. But the deploy fails.

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build xxx status: FAILURE
go: github.com/go-redis/redis/v9@v9.0.0-rc.1 requires
        github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.5: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
        go mod download github.com/onsi/ginkgo
```

Cloud build log:

```
Running "go build -o /layers/google.go.build/bin/main . (GOCACHE=/layers/google.go.build/gocache)"
go: github.com/go-redis/redis/v9@v9.0.0-rc.1 requires
    github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.5: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
    go mod download github.com/onsi/ginkgo
Done "go build -o /layers/google.go.build/bin/main . (GOCACHE=/lay..." (7.516802ms)
Failure: (ID: 721b15b4) go: github.com/go-redis/redis/v9@v9.0.0-rc.1 requires
    github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.5: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
    go mod download github.com/onsi/ginkgo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-5577006791947779410 /builder/outputs/output"
Done "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-5577006791947779410 /builder/o..." (3.938721ms)
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

Running the suggested `go mod download github.com/onsi/ginkgo` does not solve anything.
Also tried `go mod tidy` as suggested in another posts but same results. Also tried with vendor folder, but nothing again.

This is my app.yaml

`runtime: go116`

go.mod

```
module notams/anac
go 1.19

require (
    github.com/go-redis/redis/v9 v9.0.0-rc.1
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.4.0
    golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20221019170559-20944726eadf
)

require (
    github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/dgryski/go-rendezvous v0.0.0-20200823014737-9f7001d12a5f // indirect
)
```

go.sum

```
github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.2 h1:YRXhKfTDauu4ajMg1TPgFO5jnlC2HCbmLXMcTG5cbYE=
github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.2/go.mod h1:VGX0DQ3Q6kWi7AoAeZDth3/j3BFtOZR5XLFGgcrjCOs=
github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 h1:vj9j/u1bqnvCEfJOwUhtlOARqs3+rkHYY13jYWTU97c=
github.com/dgryski/go-rendezvous v0.0.0-20200823014737-9f7001d12a5f h1:lO4WD4F/rVNCu3HqELle0jiPLLBs70cWOduZpkS1E78=
github.com/dgryski/go-rendezvous v0.0.0-20200823014737-9f7001d12a5f/go.mod h1:cuUVRXasLTGF7a8hSLbxyZXjz+1KgoB3wDUb6vlszIc=
github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.4.9 h1:hsms1Qyu0jgnwNXIxa+/V/PDsU6CfLf6CNO8H7IWoS4=
github.com/go-redis/redis/v9 v9.0.0-rc.1 h1:/+bS+yeUnanqAbuD3QwlejzQZ+4eqgfUtFTG4b+QnXs=
github.com/go-redis/redis/v9 v9.0.0-rc.1/go.mod h1:8et+z03j0l8N+DvsVnclzjf3Dl/pFHgRk+2Ct1qw66A=
github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.8 h1:e6P7q2lk1O+qJJb4BtCQXlK8vWEO8V1ZeuEdJNOqZyg=
github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0 h1:i40aqfkR1h2SlN9hojwV5ZA91wcXFOvkdNIeFDP5koI=
github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0/go.mod h1:DVbg23sWSpFRCP0SfiEN6jmj59UnW/n46BH5rLB71So=
github.com/joho/godotenv v1.4.0 h1:3l4+N6zfMWnkbPEXKng2o2/MR5mSwTrBih4ZEkkz1lg=
github.com/joho/godotenv v1.4.0/go.mod h1:f4LDr5Voq0i2e/R5DDNOoa2zzDfwtkZa6DnEwAbqwq4=
github.com/nxadm/tail v1.4.8 h1:nPr65rt6Y5JFSKQO7qToXr7pePgD6Gwiw05lkbyAQTE=
github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.16.5 h1:8xi0RTUf59SOSfEtZMvwTvXYMzG4gV23XVHOZiXNtnE=
github.com/onsi/gomega v1.21.1 h1:OB/euWYIExnPBohllTicTHmGTrMaqJ67nIu80j0/uEM=
github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 h1:4DBwDE0NGyQoBHbLQYPwSUPoCMWR5BEzIk/f1lZbAQM=
github.com/stretchr/testify v1.8.0 h1:pSgiaMZlXftHpm5L7V1+rVB+AZJydKsMxsQBIJw4PKk=
golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20221019170559-20944726eadf h1:nFVjjKDgNY37+ZSYCJmtYf7tOlfQswHqplG2eosjOMg=
golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20221019170559-20944726eadf/go.mod h1:cyybsKvd6eL0RnXn6p/Grxp8F5bW7iYuBgsNCOHpMYE=
golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20220722155237-a158d28d115b h1:PxfKdU9lEEDYjdIzOtC4qFWgkU2rGHdKlKowJSMN9h0=
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220722155257-8c9f86f7a55f h1:v4INt8xihDGvnrfjMDVXGxw9wrfxYyCjk0KbXjhR55s=
golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 h1:olpwvP2KacW1ZWvsR7uQhoyTYvKAupfQrRGBFM352Gk=
gopkg.in/tomb.v1 v1.0.0-20141024135613-dd632973f1e7 h1:uRGJdciOHaEIrze2W8Q3AKkepLTh2hOroT7a+7czfdQ=
gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 h1:fxVm/GzAzEWqLHuvctI91KS9hhNmmWOoWu0XTYJS7CA=
```

**EDIT 1:** Already tried to change `runtime: go` and to `runtime: go119` but those are not supported and return "invalid go runtime".

Comment: Have you tried to check on these two docs, [Go 1.12+ Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime) and [Differences between Go 1.11 and Go 1.12](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who might have this problem, I just deployed the app on **Cloud Run** instead of **App Engine** and everything runs smoothly. I was not able to deploy it on **App Engine** and i think that the only way to do so is adapting the code and modules to the latest runtime version available for GCP (currently Go 1.16).